# Правильно ли в данном предложении расставлены запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Извиняюсь за тупой вопрос) Правильно ли в данном предложении расставлены запятые?
`Всем, кто понял рофл, привет, остальным соболезную.`

Answer (score 2):

***(1)  Всем,  (2) кто понял рофл, привет, (3) остальным соболезную.***

Запятые расставлены правильно. Две первые запятые обособляют придаточное предложение (2), а третья запятая обозначает бессоюзную связь между предложениями (1) и (3).

**Пояснение**

1. Грамматика предложения следующая .  Предложение (1) эллиптического вида: ***всем привет***. Предложение (3) неполное: ***остальным (я) соболезную***. Придаточное предложение (2) относится  главному предложению (1).
2. Запятые поставлены только **по грамматическому принципу**, поэтому интонация не выражена ясно.  При чтении отдельные части предложения объединяются, ударения и паузы можно расставить **по-разному,** например:

(1) *Всем,  кто понял рофл, привЕт, // остальным соболЕзную.*

(2) *Всем,  кто пОнял рофл, // привЕт, // остальным соболЕзную.*

3. Предложение будет более понятным для прочтения, если  использовать **интонационное тире** в неполном предложении (3):

(3) *Всем,  кто пОнял рофл, привЕт, // остальнЫм – соболЕзную.*